# C++ - Counting Occurences and passing values in Vector

Tags: c++

So I believe the values from the text file go into the vector 'com', what i'm trying to do is recognize the direction then take the value next to direction, set to tmp variable, continue to read, if the direction occurs again, add the combine variable then override tmp variable, set final tmp variable to be passed on to another class. If Repeat has been 'seen' it looks at the last direction used and take the repeat value and add it to last direction used, Any help will be appreciated, sorry for any confusion in questioning

file1.txt:

```
 Forward 2
 Left 20
 Forward 1
 Repeat 3
```

fileReader.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <float>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("text1.txt");     
    string word;
    vector<float> com;

    while (file >> word)
    {
        if(std::find(std.begin(com), std.end(com), Forward) != com.end())
        {
        }

        if(std::find(std.begin(com), std.end(com), Jump) != com.end())
        {
        }

        if(std::find(std.begin(com), std.end(com), Left) != com.end()))
        {
        }

        if(std::find(std.begin(com), std.end(com), Right) != com.end()))
        {
        }

        if ((std::find(std.begin(com), std.end(com), Repeat) != com.end()))
        {
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! And format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map for parsing your input:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file("text1.txt");                      //open file
    if(!file) { /* file could not be opened */ }     //and check whether it can be used

    std::map<std::string, float> com;
    std::string lastCom;                             //last command for use in "Repeat"

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))                 //read a line at once until file end
    {
        if(line.empty()) continue;                   //and continue if it is empty

        std::string tempCom;
        float tempVal;

        std::stringstream ss(line);                  //extract command and value
        ss >> tempCom;
        ss >> tempVal;

        if(tempCom == "Repeat")
        {
            com[lastCom] += tempVal;                 //add the value to the last command
        }
        else
        {
            com[tempCom] += tempVal;                 //add the value to the current command
            lastCom = tempCom;                       //and update last command
        }
    }       
}
```

The code is untested.

Comment: Thanks, once combining it with some push back code, its works :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I prefered to rewrite your code from scratch using a different container instead of filling the blanks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string,int> moves{{"Forward", 0}, {"Left", 0}, {"Right", 0},
                                    {"Jump", 0 }, {"Repeat", 0}};

    auto iRepeat = moves.find("Repeat");
    auto iold = moves.end();

    std::ifstream iFile("text1.txt");
    if ( !iFile.good() ) return 1;

    std::string s;
    int x;                       // There aren't floats in your file...
    while ( iFile >> s >> x ) {
        auto im = moves.find(s);
        if ( im == iRepeat ) {
            if ( iold == moves.end() ) continue;    // there must be a move to repeat
            iold->second += x;
        } else if ( im != moves.end() ){
            im->second += x;                        // update the move
            iold = im;
        }
    }

    iFile.close();

    for ( auto i = moves.begin(); i != moves.end(); i++ ) { 
        if ( i != iRepeat )     // shows only the moves
            std::cout << i->first << ": " << i->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Forward: 6
Jump: 0
Left: 20
Right: 0
```